# python trying to import after installing fails

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

In my code I need to import paramiko which is not always installed.

I did something like this:

```
import sys
import subprocess

install_path='./external'
try:
    import paramiko
except:
    sys.path.insert(1, install_path)
    try:
        import paramiko
    except:
        subprocess.run([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'install', 'paramiko', '--target', install_path])
        try:
            import paramiko
        except:
            print(f'Unable to load paramiko')
            exit(-1)
```

So first time I run, I see that I install the modules to install_path but the import still fails.
Second time I'm running this code, import passes after sys.path.append

I probebly don't understand what's going on during the import process, but any ideas how I can save myself the need to use pip every time?

Thanks

Comment: The program should just fail (if this is a necessary dependency) and put the onus back on the user - `print("You need to install X to run this")`. What if they use `conda`? Also, have you tried to make this an installable package or are you just using a script?

Comment: so I tried importlib.invalidate_caches() which seems to do the magic.

Comment: I don't know of a single library that downloads dependencies at runtime but, ok